# Setup Localhost and Wamp Server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I need to setup localhost and wamp server on windows 10, can anybody point me to good website or youtube channel please. Thanks

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: I've turned on windows features on and downloaded wamp server, thats about it

Comment: Except for securing MySQL (sets MySQL without password) it's just a matter of downloading and running. Although you do need to have the Visual C/C++ redistributables. The installer prompts with links to these, so last install a couple of days ago I just clicked on the links in the prompts, downloaded them and installed them). I'm on 64bit so did this for both for each version. This link covers the install [WAMPServer 3 All you need to know](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,138295)

Comment: Ooops, forgot to say once redistributables installs just carried on with the install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here ya go

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TJtGofoD7Uw

Hope this could help you out!